# Show loading on load url of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a **loading** on load **url of an image** not on load an image. i know it possible to show loading on load an image like this:

```
var $img = $('<img id="img" src="' + src + '" />');
$img.on('load', function() {
  // hide loading
});
```

but i don't want to append an img element each time i just want to change **src** and show loading when **url** of that image is loading. is it possible?

```
$('#ThumbnailSlide img').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('data-href');
    // i want to show a loading when src is loading
    $('#img').attr('src',src);
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eor5bbb2/1/)**

any idea?
i google it but nothing found about it!

Comment: Since image are already loaded in browser cache what the use of showing loading? If your are displaying larger image then its useful

Comment: images are already loaded

Comment: how many gbs does your image got that you need a loading image ?

Comment: Beside that the images are already loaded, don't append new `img` tag, just get the it like this:

`var $img = $('#img');`

instead of: `var $img = $('<img id="img" src="' + src + '" />');`

Comment: @Satpal sorry i think i missed something, please see updated fiddle.

Comment: @azad i want to load a bigger size of that image not the same src, i made a mistake in my fiddle, please see updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onload` event of `Image`

```
$('#ThumbnailSlide img').click(function() {
    //Show loading
    $('#loading').show();

    //get 
    var src = $(this).data('href');


    var img = new Image();

    //Set src to load image
    img.src = src;

    img.onload = function() {
        //Update src property
        $('#img').prop('src', img.src);

        //Hide loading
        $('#loading').hide();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/n6sqsyLy/1/)

Comment: That's what i'm talking about! thanks for your answer.